# Adding/Removing form fields with Php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form which gives the ability for the user to add additional fields form to the form and it selects data from the database for the select/options.

It works ok but not entirely correct and am wondering if somebody wouldn't mind casting an eye on the code to see if can be done in a much cleaner way.

The main issue being that the select isn't sending the correct value across to the action script.

HTML output of the form:

```
<?php $dashboardId = $_GET['dashboard_id']; ?>

<form action="cm.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="dashboardId" value="<?php echo $dashboardId; ?>">


    <div id="exercises">
        <div class="team">
            <select name="teamId[]">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE dashboard_id = $dashboardId";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<option value="' . $row["team_id"] . '">' . $row["team_name"] . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>                
            </select>
            <button class="remove">x</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add_exercise">add more</button>
    <br>  
    <input type="text" name="memberName">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Member" />
</form>
```

So the above renders out my simple form. The second part the JQuery that handles the facility to add additional select fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() { 
    $('#exercises').append('<div class="team"><select name="teamName[]"><?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE dashboard_id = $dashboardId";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<option value="' . $row["team_id"] . '">' . $row["team_name"] . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>   </select><button class="remove">x</button></div>');
    return false; //prevent form submission
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false; //prevent form submission
}); 
</script>
```

Now as can be seen it isn't the neatest of solutions combining the jQuery with the Php however I am not sure how else I would separate it out? So what is happening is when I do a `var_dump($_POST)` I see that the generated select passes `["teamName"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "211"` where it should be passing `["teamId"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "211"`

**I am fully aware it is open to SQL injection but for now I am just trying to make this little part work.**

**update - team table scehema**

[image]

Comment: Could you please give us the schema for you "teams" table?

Comment: 1. make the button type="button" 2. NEVER call anything `name="submit"` in a form. It will break the event handler 3. please post the rendered HTML in a [mcve] by clicking the `<>` button in the editor

Comment: Try to use ajax on button click use ajax and get dropdown data and the append .... i think it's works

Comment: @x3ns I have added it to the question.

Comment: @SujalPatel is it possible to show me an example?

Comment: @SujalPatel I have made those tweaks to the form.

Comment: @PhpDude: You have `<select name="teamName[]">` in your javascript block. Should be `<select name="teamId[]">` according to what you want.

Comment: @x3ns for goodness sake. That looks like it has done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main.php File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
  <select class="options" name="">
    <option value="1">item_1</option>
    <option value="1">item_2</option>
    <option value="1">item_3</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="addme" name="button">Add More</button>
 </body>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.addme').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'getData.php',
      type:'GET',
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
          $('.wrapper').append(result);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

getData.php File

```
<select>
<option value='1'>Item1</option>
<option value='2'>Item2</option>
<option value='3'>Item3</option>
</select><br>
```

In this example getData file data was static but you have write query to get dropdown list data and pass in success response.